# jQuery count each item and number them 02, 03, 04 except first item text should be "Up Next"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not great with jQuery, so far this is what i got from checking through stackoverflow and other resources:

```
var counter = 1;
$('.next-page .nav-item').each(function () {

  if ($(this, ':gt(0)')) {
    $(this).find('.view-title').html('Up Next');
  } else {
    $(this).find('.view-title').html('0' + counter);
  }
  counter++;

});
```

Basically the output should end up like this in the html:

```
<div class="nav-item">
  <span class="view-title">Up Next</span>
  <span>Kits</span>
</div>

<div class="nav-item">
  <span class="view-title">02</span>
  <span>GUI</span>
</div>

<div class="nav-item">
  <span class="view-title">03</span>
  <span>UI</span>
</div>

<div class="nav-item">
  <span class="view-title">04</span>
  <span>Other</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show this in a jsFiddle? That would be much more easier to understand!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like

```
$('.next-page .nav-item').each(function (i , val) {
    $(this).find('.view-title').html(!i ? 'Up Next' : '0' + (i+1));
});
```

Comment: Glad it helps :-)

Comment: @user2810762, Remember to mark this answer as accepted.  It might help the next person find the right answer

Comment: Ye, just had to wait 10 minutes :)